# Removing spaces from the two sides of a text line

Tags: c, text, tabs, space

I am supposed to write a simple program that strips the lines of their trailing spaces and tabs. It should be written with the most basic tools in C (No pointers and libraries).

```
/* Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each
line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines. */

#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int gettline(char s[], int lim);
void inspect_line(char s[], int limit, int start, int end);

main()
{
    int len, i, start, end;
    start = 0;
    end = MAXLINE;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    while ((len = gettline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0){
            inspect_line(line, MAXLINE, start, end);
            for(i=start; i<end-1;++i)
                printf("%c",line[i]);
        }
    printf("\n");   
    return 0;
}

/* gettline: read a line into s, return length */
int gettline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* inspect_line: determines the indices to the start and the end of the sentence */
void inspect_line(char s[], int limit, int start, int end)
{
    while((s[start]!=' ') && (start<limit-1))
        ++start;
    while(!(s[end]>=33 && s[end]<=126))
        --end;
}
```

when I run it, I get a strange result:

[image]

I am not sure what the problem is and I have been trying to debug it for hours with no result.

Comment: What do you get when you use %s instead of %c in your printf statements?

Comment: I get the error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: A seg fault means you are trying to access memory that you aren't supposed to. Try implementing @dasblinkenlight's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is going on: when you write

```
inspect_line(line, MAXLINE, start, end);
for(i=start; i<end-1;++i)
    printf("%c",line[i]);
```

you assume that the values set to `start` and `end` inside `inspect_line` function would be transferred to `main`; that assumption is incorrect. In C parameters are passed by value. That is why `start` and `end` remain what they were before the call.

You can fix this by passing pointers to `start` and `end` into the `inspect_line` function. Of course you would need to change the function to accept and use pointers, too:

```
void inspect_line(char s[], int *start, int *end)
{
    while(isspace(s[*start]) && (*start < *end))
        ++(*start);
    while(isspace(s[*end]) && (*start < *end))
        --(*end);
}
```

the call would look like this:

```
// Note that passing MAXLINE is no longer necessary
inspect_line(line, &start, &end);
for(i=start ; i <= end-1 ; ++i) // both start and end are inclusive
    printf("%c",line[i]);
```

You would also need to re-initialize `start` and `end` between each iteration of the loop, setting `start` to zero and `end` to the current value of `len`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are right, both `start` and `end` are inclusive.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented what you said. But one problem still persists and that is the gibberish that comes after the result. When I run the program now, it correctly strips the line of its end spaces, but then comes this mass of crap afterwards (like in the picture)

Comment: @novice66 put `start = 0; end = len;` before `inspect_line(line, MAXLINE, &start, &end);`.  and `i <= end-1` --> `i <= end` BTW you allow `isspace` and `int *start, int *end`.

Comment: YAY, It worked! I had falsely reset `start` and `end` after the `inspect_line`. Thank you guys for your patience!